# Cannot "Run as JUnit Plug-in test" on test plugin/package (JUnit5)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, tycho, junit5

I'm trying to add JUnit5 support in my Eclipse RCP application. It almost works, because for now I can:

- Use Maven to build whole application and run tests with Tycho
- Run single JUnit5 tests (creating run configuration on specific class) in
  Eclipse
- Run single JUnit5 tests in Run as `JUnit Plug-in test` mode in Eclipse
- Run multiple JUnit5 tests in `Run as JUnit test` mode in Eclipse

What I'm trying to achieve now is to be able to run whole sets of test classes in plug-in test mode. For JUnit4-based plug-ins I could simply right-click on whole package or even whole plug-in and invoke Run `As -> JUnit Plug-in test`.

When I do the same operation on JUnit5 tests I get an error: `No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'`.

My current configuration for such plug-ins looks as follows:

- According to [official instructions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/JUnit5) in MANIFEST.FM I have **Import-Package** dependencies:

  ```
   org.junit.jupiter.api,
   org.junit.jupiter.params,
   org.junit.jupiter.params.provider
  ```

  and `org.junit` as **Require-Bundle** dependency
- In order to run tests in Eclipse IDE I've also added JUnit 5 library to Java Build Path of the plugin. I coudn't add JUnit 5 runner dependencies to MANIFEST.FM instead, because of [conflict with Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534587).